# Postgres 9.4: Replicate only one database from one instance to another

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-9.4

I have postgresql 9.4 running in 5432 port with 2 databases. Now I want to create another instance in 5433 port (passive) and replicate only one database from 5432 instance (active). All table and data changes in database in 5432 instance (active) should replicate to the database in 5433 instance (passive).

I also have to create **another database** in 5433 instance (passive) and do **CRUD operation in new database**

Do we have a way to do this in postgres?

Comment: Are you aware that Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)? In 9.4 you can only replicate the whole cluster ("instance") using streaming replication. If you were using a current version of Postgres you could use [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html) to replicate a single database

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) We have an existing postgres 9.4 instance running in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streaming replication cannot do that, and logical replication (which could do that) was introduced in v10.

So your best option would be to upgrade.

Apart from that, you'd have to resort to legacy trigger-based replication solutions like Slony.